# Django Error: vertualenv EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Tags: django

I get the following error when I try to install MySQL-python within virtualenv on a MAC running 10.8.

```
vertualenv EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a simple fix just to edit the /bin/activate file from the virtualenv directory and add the following lines,

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/"
export PATH
```

That's it, just make sure you match your paths to your own configuration. Now MySQL-python installs under virtualenv as normal.

Link: http://glynjackson.org/weblog/entry/fix-vertualenv-environmenterror-mysql_config-not-found.html

Comment: adding this line `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/"` has done the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Also it can help you, especially if you use MacOS X

```bash
pip install MySQL-python (error)

echo "mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config" >> ~/.virtualenvs/ENV_NAME/build/MySQL-python/site.cfg

pip install MySQL-python (it's ok)
```

Comment: This worked for me, though I am using MAMP and had to adjust the path to: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config`