# MySQL-Python install - Could not build the egg

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, ioerror

I'm trying to setup python mysql. I'm working through the following tutorial:

http://anthonyscherba.com/site/blog/django-mysql-install-mac

I'm all good until set 5. When I run

```
$ python setup.py clean
```

and I get in return

```
 /Users/msmith/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/Users/msmith/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/Users/msmith/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "/Users/msmith/Downloads/MySQL-python-1.2.4b4/distribute_setup.py", line 116, in _build_egg
    raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')
IOError: Could not build the egg.
```

Comment: You should explicitly state that you're on a Mac, and perhaps indicate which specific point-release.

Comment: I searched for 'install python-mysql on mac os x' it produced a number of useful resources including: http://www.markomedia.com.au/installing-python-mysqldb-on-os-x/

I've had luck with version 1.2.4 (not b4)

Comment: No luck, I tried starting over and doing it through his strategy and I arrived at the same error. I am running mac OS X 10.8.4 and MySQL-python-1.2.4b4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success following these tips:

First try installing with pip:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Then: (From here: [Django Error: vertualenv EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314791/django-error-vertualenv-environmenterror-mysql-config-not-found))

```
echo "mysql_config = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config" >> ~/.virtualenvs/ENV_NAME/build/MySQL-python/site.cfg
```

Then, (from here: [cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-null-conversion" within installing python-mysql on mac 10.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127493/cc1-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-wno-null-conversion-within-insta))

"Try to Remove cflags -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-unused-private-field [from] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config."

then, simply install again:
    pip install mysql-python

Then (from here: [Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib))

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Then it should work!

Comment: How can you run pip the second time? When I do, I get the error `pip can't proceed with requirement 'mysql-python' due to a pre-existing build directory...` I have to delete the directory from the previous run (which of course removes the site.cfg file).

Comment: Beats me, never had that issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing helped for me. I had to update MySQL-python to 1.2.5, and that resolved the issue.

```
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

Comment: it's wierd,I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this version fixes this problem.

https://github.com/qingfeng/MySQLdb1/tree/MySQL-python-1.2.4

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue...my requirements.txt file looks as bellow:

```
Django==1.6
MySQL-python==1.2.4
South==0.8.4
...
distribute==0.6.31
```

What worked for me was:

1. Comment the line for MySQL-python
2. Execute the "pip install -r requirements.txt"
3. Uncomment again MySQL-python
4. Run again the pip install.

So, I think that the issue is some kind of dependency with the "distribute" version installed (OR to be installed in my case).

Comment: Just had this issue and your resolution worked for me aswell. This was for mysql-python 1.2.5 on SLES.